# es6 export default was not found but works from inside node_modules

Tags: npm, node-modules, es6-module-loader

There's the library I load with npm: @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic. It works. I can use by

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
```

After that I pull the target file (it's specified in package.json as ./build/ckeditor.js) and put it outside of node_modules to the project's root.

I try to use it by

```
import ClassicEditor from './ckeditor'
```

But it does not work. The error is

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'ClassicEditor') was not found in 'ckeditor'
```

Why so? There's no `export default` construction indeed, but it works somehow from node_modules. How to make it work outside of node_modules?

Comment: I have the same issue with another module. I copied the whole folder to my projects folder but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

To make CKEditor work in the `<script type="module">` element, type:

```
import {} from './ckeditor.js'
```

or, simply:

```
import './ckeditor.js'
```